# Synchronize data from the production Azure SQL database with the staging database allowing changes to be made in the second

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, devops, backup

I have two databases in **Azure SQL Database** almost identical in their structure (unless one of the two is modified). I need to **synchronize** the data from the **production** database with the **staging** database, being able to make changes in staging without harming production unless I need to do a production restore (that's another topic).
In the case that there is no solution, I want to be able to make staging equal to production when my developers need it, is there a way to modify a database with a backup of another without having to create a new database (since you would have to modify the server name in the app)

Comment: How would you synchronize data across databases with different schemas? For example, suppose on staging you execute something like `alter table T add column_c int not null`. What is your expectation? Should the system magically make up values to put in this new non nullable column when copying data from prod? You need to alter your premise: dev and test databases should not be expected to need production data because it's not a coherent idea given that the schemas are probably not the same

Comment: @allmhuran Ok, I follow you. My idea does not make sense if a mandatory column is created in staging and then it would break. They are also very large databases and generating a trigger together with a procedure would be difficult.
Should I change the question to just "update staging with a production backup"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process I currently employ across my environments is:

1. Start with a baseline where STAGING and PROD are exactly the same. This you can achieve by restoring the latest backup(s) from your PROD environment to your STAGING environment.
2. As changes occur in DEV and need to be released to STAGING, create the appropriate release scripts to apply to STAGING.
3. When you need to refresh the data in STAGING, restore the latest backup(s) from PROD to STAGING again.
4. Optional: Run any post-refresh STAGING specific scripts that are needed. E.g. if you obfuscate any of the data, or change of the data to signify it's the STAGING environment.
5. Run any release scripts in STAGING, that **haven't** yet been released to PROD.
6. Over time your release scripts that were used in STAGING, should get used to release to PROD, which is what will help keep the two environments in sync.
7. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 at the frequency acceptable to your goals.

I have the above in a SQL Job so it's essentially a one click process, but my database is SQL Server on-prem. I also use a schema comparison tool called [SQL Examiner](https://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql-examiner/) to automate generating the release scripts I need, but not sure it's applicable to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Great, sounds good to me. But I can't find a way in Azure to do a staging restore with a production backup without creating a new database. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPortillaKitroser Is your PROD database hosted on the same server as your STAGING database?

Comment: Yes! That is the idea

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPortillaKitroser Also, what kind of backups are you using? It sounds like there are different options for Azure SQL Database, between "automated backups", "point-in-time recovery", or just a regular .bak file stored in blob storage.

Comment: None for now, we are doing a conceptual test and I was commissioned to see how we would do this task, so we could use any... Likewise, the one that sounds best to me is "point-in-time recovery"